# django-summernote

Tags: python, django

Есть блог хотел в нём сделать редактор статьи.

Установил всё по инструкции

https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation

Выкладывая пост из админ-панели, редактор django-summernote работает, но как только я сохраняю и перехожу в публикацию на самом сайте вижу вот это безобразие

```
 <b> считает теги просто текстом </b>
```

подскажите может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

нужно поместить в

```
   {% autoescape off %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ name|safe }}
```

Пример:

```
{{ object.title }} <br>
{{ object.text|safe }}
```

используйте в шаблоне при выводе фильтр safe.